# Using AJAX to post information to Flask

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask

I am currently trying to send value from the dropdown selection to Flask in order to update the html but Flask does not seem to be sending a valid json response.
This is the section of the html and ajax

```
$(function() {
      $("form").on("submit", function(event){
        event.preventDefault()
        $.ajax({
          data: {
            box1 : $("#box1").val()
          },
          type:"POST",
          url : "/process"
        })
        .done(function(data){
          $("#site1").attr("href",data.site1);
          $("#image1").attr("src", data.image1);
        });
      });
    });

<form >
      <div class="control">
        <div class="select">
          <select class="is-hovered" id="box1" onchange="this.form.submit()">
            <option>Select News Sites here</option>
            <option value="cnn">CNN</option>
            <option value="nbc">NBC</option>
            <option value="fox">Fox</option>
          </select>
        </div></div></form>
```

And this is what I have on Flask

```
@app.route("/process", methods=['POST'])
def homepage_process():
    box1 = request.form['box1']
    cnnimg1 = "static/screenshot/{}".format(cnn_screenshot[-1])
    nbcimg1 = "static/screenshot/{}".format(nbc_screenshot[-1])
    foximg1 = "static/screenshot/{}".format(fox_screenshot[-1])
    cnnimg2 = "static/screenshot/{}".format(cnn_screenshot[-4])
    nbcimg2 = "static/screenshot/{}".format(nbc_screenshot[-4])
    foximg2 = "static/screenshot/{}".format(fox_screenshot[-4])
    if str(box1) == 'cnn':
        img1=cnnimg1
        site1= "http://cnn.com/"
    elif str(box1) == 'nbc':
        img1=nbcimg1
        site1= "http://nbcnews.com/"
    elif str(box1) == 'fox':
        img1=foximg1
        site1= "http://foxnews.com/"
    return jsonify({'img1':img1,'sit1':site1})
```

If anyone could point me to the right direction to fix the issue it will be much appreciated.

Comment: Check your network tab in your developer tools to see what response you get

Comment: It seems AJAX is not posting to the Flask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The submit method on the form does not trigger the submit handler, a way around this would be to bind the ajax request to the select's change event.

```
$(function() {
      $("#box1").on("change", function(event){
        $.ajax({
          data: {
            box1 : $("#box1").val()
          },
          type:"POST",
          url : "/process"
        })
        .done(function(data){
          $("#site1").attr("href",data.site1);
          $("#image1").attr("src", data.image1);
        });
      });
});
```

```
<form >
      <div class="control">
        <div class="select">
          <select class="is-hovered" id="box1">
            <option>Select News Sites here</option>
            <option value="cnn">CNN</option>
            <option value="nbc">NBC</option>
            <option value="fox">Fox</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver, that fixes the issue

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo, `sit1` should be `site1` in your jsonify function. Same goes for image, `img1` should be `image1`.

Your keys in the jsonified dictionairy must match the keys you're using in js.

Comment: I fixed the typo but still not getting a response.

Comment: Is the server getting the request?

Comment: No it appears the server is not getting a post request. Perhaps it is not submitting the value?

Comment: Yes it isn't you're sending another GET request instead. This has nothing to do with flask, but is a jquery/js issue. The form is not being submitted, because it has no `method="POST"` in the `<form>` tag.

Comment: on the form should i refer the post to "#"

Comment: I tried this  <form action="#" method="post"> but now I am getting this error. "ValueError: View function did not return a response"

Comment: That means that flask is not sending back any data. Which is weird, because if you're still using the same python script as in your flask route, it should send back a response. Did you change anything?

Comment: No, the flask side is unchanged the whole time. But changing the html from submit to change on the handler fixed the issue. It was a little weird that it was not posting the data on submit. Thanks for the help.